# How to define the order of a composite / multi column primary key using typeorm

Tags: node.js, typeorm

Using typeorm how do you set the order of a composite / multi column primary key.

I expect/want the below entity to generate

```
PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`id`),
```

but instead i get

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`date`),
```

**entity**

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, Index } from "typeorm";
import { CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, DeleteDateColumn } from "../decorators/timestamps";

    @Entity()
    @Index("indx_popularity", ["date", "score", "entity_type"], { unique: false })
    @Index("indx_id", ["id"], { unique: true })
    export class EntityScore {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;
    
        @Column({ length: 36 })
        entity_id: string;
    
        @Column({ length: 36 })
        entity_type: string;
    
        @Column({ type: "decimal", precision: 4, scale: 3 })
        score: number;
    
        @Column({ type: "json", nullable: true })
        raw: {};
    
        @Column({ primary: true, type: "date" })
        date: Date;
    
        @CreateDateColumn({})
        created_at: string;
    
        @UpdateDateColumn({})
        updated_at: string;
    
        @DeleteDateColumn({})
        deleted_at: string;
    }
```

Note: **manually modifying the migration file after it has been created is not an acceptable solution**. I am looking for a solution that involves updating the entity definition itself. Simply because we can't keep track of these manual alterations and we have a usecase where doing local development we use synchronise=true which does not use migration files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I know its a bit late but I solved it by simply changing the order that the columns were declared.

I.E

This produces the follow PK order:

`CONSTRAINT "PK_28c1939ced27db911687a0c4bce" PRIMARY KEY (issue_count ASC, project_name ASC),`

```
@Entity({ name: 'issues' })
export class Issue {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  issueCount: number;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  @ManyToOne(() => Project)
  @JoinColumn([
    { name: 'project_name', referencedColumnName: 'name' },
  ])
  projectName: Project;
}
```

But swapping it around does this:

```
@Entity({ name: 'issues' })
export class Issue {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  @ManyToOne(() => Project)
  @JoinColumn([
    { name: 'project_name', referencedColumnName: 'name' },
  ])
  projectName: Project;

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  issueCount: number;
}
```

Gave me:

`CONSTRAINT "PK_28c1939ced27db911687a0c4bce" PRIMARY KEY (project_name ASC, issue_count ASC),`